# To select the vertex at the highest point on the z-axis in edit mode

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

When modifying the Hi-Poly model, I would like to find and select the vertex at the highest point on the z-axis, but is there a simple way to find this vertex?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy this Python script and paste it into the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) within *Scripting Tab*. Then select the object and press *Run Script* button. It will automatically select the highest vertex on the local z-axis.

[image]

Here's the script:

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.object.data

z = -100000
i = -1

for v in mesh.vertices:
    if z > v.co.z:
        continue
    z = v.co.z
    i = v.index

mesh.vertices[i].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```